# Email contact form not sending mail

Tags: email, email-contact-form

My email contact form doesnt work at all. I can send email throught he system "send mail" but not a form.

My code looks like this:

```
{exp:email:contact_form user_recipients="no" recipients="xxx@xxx.com" redirect="2" return="{site_url}contact" charset="utf-8"}
            
            <div class="contact-form w-form">
              <div id="email-form" name="email-form" data-name="Email Form" class="mail-form w-clearfix">
              <input type="text" class="text-field-name w-input" maxlength="256" name="name" data-name="Name" placeholder="Name" id="name"><input type="email" class="text-field-email w-input" maxlength="256" name="email" data-name="Email" placeholder="Email" id="email" required="">
              <input type="text" class="text-field-subject w-input" maxlength="256" name="Subject" data-name="Subject" placeholder="Subject" id="Subject" required="">
              <textarea placeholder="Please write your message here ..." maxlength="5000" id="Message" name="message" data-name="Message" class="text-area-message w-input"></textarea>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button w-button">
              </div>
              
            </div>
{/exp:email:contact_form}
```

Answer (score 0):

@paul You need to include a `from` input, even if it's just hidden. See the docs here: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/add-ons/email.html#from